# Laptop Monitor not turning on with two external monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, xrandr

I have a Dell Inspiron N7010 set up with two external monitors. 
[System Settings Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYZiC.png)
The problem I'm facing is I cannot get the laptop monitor as well as my two external monitors to all turn on and extend my desktop.

I've managed to have all 3 screens on, but I could only get them to be clones of each other, which is not what I need.

Currently I have my two external monitors extending each other with my laptop screen not turning on at all.

When I run `xrandr` I get the following output:
[xrandr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6XS2.png)

I tried to run (LVDS1 is my laptop screen)
`xrandr --output LVDS1 --off`
`xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1600x900 --rate 60`

But I get `xrandr: cannot find crtc for output LVDS1` 
Any advice for this? Thanks!